# Иероглифы при работе с KCFinder

Tags: php, кодировка, yii2, openserver

В качестве файлового менеджера **(ФМ)** использую KCFinder, работает всё отлично, но при попытке переименовать или создать файл/папку через этот ФМ, то на сервере всё папки имеют имена типа `РІС‹РІР°РІС‹Р°С‹РІР°С‹`, хотя при отображении в ФМ всё нормально отображается.

Пытался изменить код ФМ, в частности где сохраняется или редактируется имя файла, преобразовую имя в UTF-8, но сохраняет всё-равно в иэроглифах.

Это проблема сервера или всё же где-то ФМ меняет кодировку окончательно?

Answer (score 1):

Вот код, воспроизводящий вашу ситуацию:

```
$string = 'вывавыаываы';

echo $encoding = mb_detect_encoding($string);
echo mb_convert_encoding($string, 'utf-8', 'cp1251');
```

Вы пытаетесь преобразовать строку к `utf-8`, считая что кодировка `cp1251`. Но строка уже записана в кодировке `utf-8`. Попробуйте в коде убрать преобразование, либо выполняйте смену кодировки следующим способом:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding($string, 'utf-8', mb_detect_encoding($string));
```